# Automating gradle to build the application package(.apk) from the code

Tags: android, android-studio, jenkins, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Recently, I was working on a project in which we have a code-base and we make some changes in the application and make the application available for testing to the tester.

The changes are variables changes such as our test site name, icon and splash screen.

What we are trying to achieve is that without opening Android Studio, we can make the application package(.apk) for the code base that we have. It will save a lot of time for us

We have searched for several options which are Jenkins CI etc, but have not been able to do so.

Any sort of help regarding this topic will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run a gradle task from the console / terminal.

Go to the project root folder and run gradle + command, generally the command is `gradle assembleDebug` or `gradle assembleRelease` depending on the build type you are aiming for.

You can check the existing gradle tasks on Android Studio [image]